# Get Device using GUID always fails

Tags: c++, winapi, guid, ports

I am attempting to get information(location info, location path, etc.) about a device that is currently connected to the computer in C++ Win32. I know how to get this information by using the function [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Before I use the function `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()`, I must first call [SetupDiGetSelectedDevice()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) because I need to pass a `SP_DEVINFO_DATA` as a parameter inside `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()`. Is this correct?

**My Problem:** I can never get the device using the function `SetupDiGetSelectedDevice()`. When I call that function it always fails, ie, returns FALSE. `GetLastError()` returns the code e0000211 which I am not sure what that means.

Whats going wrong with my following code? If I am using the wrong function to *get* a device then what function do I use to get a device?

```
INT_PTR WINAPI WinProcCallback( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
        {
            TCHAR strBuff[256];

            PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR h = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR) lParam;
            if (h->dbch_devicetype != DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE) {
                printf("h->dbch_devicetype != DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE\n");
                break;
            }

            switch (wParam)
            {
                case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                {
                    DWORD dataT = 0;
                SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData = {0};
                deviceInfoData.cbSize          = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
                deviceInfoData.ClassGuid       = h->dbcc_classguid;

               // The following function always works and is successful
                HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&h->dbcc_classguid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
                if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                    printf("hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE\n");
                    break;
                }

               // ERROR OCCURS HERE: The following function ALWAYS returns false: whats going wrong?
                if (SetupDiGetSelectedDevice(hDevInfo, &deviceInfoData) == FALSE) {
                    printf("SetupDiGetSelectedDevice(hDevInfo, &deviceInfoData) == FALSE\n");
                    break;
                }

               // Get device location information
               DWORD buffersize = 0;
                LPTSTR buffer    = NULL;
                while (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo,  &deviceInfoData, SPDRP_LOCATION_INFORMATION, &dataT,
                                                                   (PBYTE)buffer, buffersize, &buffersize))
                {
                    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
                        // Change the buffer size.
                        if (buffer) 
                            LocalFree(buffer);
                        buffer = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, buffersize);
                    }
                }

                printf("Data: %d: %s\n", i, buffer);
                }
                break;
```

Comment: *The function returns TRUE if it is successful. Otherwise, it returns FALSE and the logged error can be retrieved with a call to GetLastError.* Knowing a function failed, but having no idea why isn't very fun at all. You use it later on, but not there.

Comment: @chris Thanks for the comment. I;ve updated my post with the error code. Its e0000211 but from googling(and searching msdn) I cant find what that error code represents.

Comment: So in the `if` body after the function returns false, `GetLastError` returns 3758096913?

Comment: @chris no in decimal format the error is -536870383 but yes GetLastError() is call from within the if statement brackets

Comment: Same thing, but `GetLastError` returns an unsigned value. I was just wondering.

Comment: That's odd, I can't even find the one they mention in the parameters section (`ERROR_NO_DEVICE_SELECTED`). Is there a separate list for driver development somewhere?

Comment: @chris not sure. Heres the page for SP_DEVINFO_DATA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Well, good news. I found the list in setupapi.h. It actually happens to be `ERROR_NO_DEVICE_SELECTED`. I've never done any driver stuff at all, so I don't know which action to recommend, but two that come to mind are calling the `SetDevice` version of it first, or using some sort of `GetExistingDeviceInformationSet` (not a real name) function.